# Is there any official documentation from Intel on cache distribution?

Tags: caching, x86, intel

Is there some official document from Intel on exactly **which levels of cache are shared between cores and which layers are specific to each core**, as well as how much is in each level?

I am running on `Xeon X3470`, which is part of the `E5` family of processors.

I found [this page](http://ark.intel.com/products/42932/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X3470-%288M-Cache-2_93-GHz%29?wapkw=x3470) from Intel, but it does not specify how much there is of each type of cache, and whether it is shared between cores or specific to each core. I also found [this article](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/Intel-i7-nehalem-cpu,2041-10.html) discussing caching structure, but I am not sure where the data comes from.

Also, the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` would have me believe that each hyperthread has `8 MB` of some sort of cache independently, but that seems hard to believe.

Answer (score 0):

[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors) shows that this CPU has - 4 × 256 KB of L2 caches, plus 8MB L3 cache. Since there are 4 cores, it means the L2 is private per core, while the L3 is shared.

For a more official source, you could refer to the [optimization guide](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html) (the link may change, but it's easy to find through google).
Section 2.4 on that link deals with "Nehalem" based CPUs, and 2.4.4 deals specifically with the cache subsystem, also stating that the L1/L2 are per core and the L3 is shared (unified in this context means instructions + data, not to be confused with shared which is between multiple cores).
[image]

/proc/cpuinfo just shows the overall available space on each level, it's not private per thread, just the limit. You can see a few examples of the expected output [here](http://www.richweb.com/cpu_info)